# Localize output of strtotime string

Tags: php, date, strtotime, strftime

I read through manuals concerning strtotime and strftime as well as related functions, but I cannot seem to make any progress in trying to solve my problem.

Basically, I'm interested in ways to print output of $deldate5 in local language (Dutch in this case).

```
$deldate5 = date("d.m.Y., l", strtotime("today + 5 day", time()));
```

I would most likely need to ditch strtotime string and replace it with something else in order to facilitate "today + 5 day" parameter.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)?

Comment: Strftime would be great but I'm having trouble making it work in such fashion. I'd like it to "recognize" which day is today+5 days and print it out in given format and in local language.

Comment: Well that should actually work straight away, I mean that's for what that function is for. `strtotime` creates the timestamp, `strftime` the localized and formatted output. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am pretty sure I am missing something, since my php knowledge is rather limited (yet growing!). Would you mind putting up a syntax for me?

Comment: I tried in an answer below and it came to my attention that I might have misread your question. You can follow my thoughts in the answer, maybe you can add some more information what your actual question is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's pick this apart:

```
$deldate5 = date("d.m.Y., l", strtotime("today + 5 day", time()));
```

This is doing two things:

1. `strtotime`: Create a UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since the epoch).
2. `date`: Format the output.

Your problem is related to the output (2.), not creating the timestamp (1.). So let's put this apart:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("today + 5 day", time());
$formatted = date("d.m.Y., l", $timestamp);
```

The only thing required now is to deal with the following line of code:

```
$formatted = date("d.m.Y., l", $timestamp);
```

The formatting parameters for the [`date`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/date) function are:

```
d - Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
m - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
Y - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
l - A full textual representation of the day of the week
```

As `l` (lower case L) requires a locale in your output, let's see which formatting parameter [`strftime`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strftime) has to offer that is similar:

```
%A - A full textual representation of the day.
```

So it's just a small step to change from `date` to `strftime`:

```
$formatted = strftime("%d.%m.%Y., %A", $timestamp);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to dig into this problem. Actually, "l" (lower case L) is used for textual representation of the day of the week. And this is where the problem is. I am outputting $deldate5 as one of options in drop-down list and I'd like "l" to be displayed in local language. I hope this sheds more light on issue I have.

Comment: @TomislavŠtajduhar: Updated the answer, I've misread that character. This should do it now, and I hope you understand the pattern.

Comment: Wonderful, it works! Many thanks, this helped a lot and I learned quite a bit! :) I would vote up but apparently I need some more rep for that (freshly registered today).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the date default timezone to your local timezone:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php